# Telerik Upload control on Ajax ModalPopupExtender in IE8 Compatibility Mode

Tags: asp.net, telerik, ie8-compatibility-mode

I have an internal site that runs under IE8 with Intranet settings, and thus runs in Compatibilty mode.  I do not have the access or permission to force the site into regular mode using headers or IIS - in other words, it must run in Compatibility mode.

On the site, I have an Upload control that resides on an asp:Panel, that is associated with the ajax control toolkit's ModalPopupExtender.  The Upload control is set to use 3 input boxes.

When the user opens the modal, and I have enablefileinputskinning="false", the input boxes have an inline style assigned from the Compatibility mode that sets the width as 15px.

[image: enablefileskin=false]

If I set the enablefileinputskinning="true", the input boxes are the correct size, but are transparent through the modal down to the page, and the user can't interact with the elements

[image: enablefileskin=true]

Any thoughts or ideas on how to get the input boxes to show correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working with Telerik support, they provided the answer (using enablefileinputskinning='false'):

```
.ruFileWrap
{
    width:380px !important;
}
```